# Value not returning right

Tags: arrays, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a issue getting my code to return the correct value.

I am building spreadsheet to help me with cooking for a video game I play. I am trying to track the amount of all the ingredients I have for cooking. I want to be able to update the amount I have from a dashboard rather than go scroll through the list to find each ingredient individually.

Here is what I have setup so far.

I have a page called Updater where I am selecting from a drop down a certain ingredient(cell A2). Next to that drop down is cell for me to enter a new amount of that ingredient that I have(cell B2).

The second page is called Ingredients. This has a 2 columns. Column 1 is a list of the ingredients and in column 2 is the number I currently have on hand.

The script I have written so far can find me the row number, but when I try to get the current amount I have for the ingredient to make sure the code is working, it doesnt return anything in the log.

There is my code

```
function finalTest(){
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var fs = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Ingredients");
var ts = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Updater");

var data = fs.getDataRange().getValues();
var luItem = ts.getRange("A2").getValue();
var newAmt = ts.getRange("B2").getValue();
var rn = 0;
Logger.log(rn);
Logger.log(newAmt);
Logger.log(data);
Logger.log(luItem);

        for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
            if(data[i][0] == luItem){ //[1] because column B
              Logger.log((i+1))
              return i+1;
              
            }
        }
rn = i;
Logger.log(rn);
var fsr = fs.getRange(rn,2).getValue();
Logger.log(fsr);

}
```

Right now the logger will return up to where it logs "i", but will not return the new rn or fsr values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what spreadsheet software are you using, what language is your code in?

Comment: Google Sheets - google apps script

Answer (score 0):

A function immediately returns on the `return` statement. So you can only return one value there - or an object with multiple values inside.

As it looks that you just want to log data out, you would have to do that inside the if, but before the `return` to reach:

```javascript
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == luItem) {

        // first do all the logging
        Logger.log(i + 1);
        rn = i;
        Logger.log(rn);
        var fsr = fs.getRange(rn,2).getValue();
        Logger.log(fsr);

        // and then return from the function
        return i + 1;      
    }

    // what should be returned here??
}
```

Please also note that you should return a value or handle it somehow else when the loop runs through and the condition is never met.

If the return value then is still `i + 1`, you could make the `if`-condition instead part of the stop condition of the loop:

```javascript
var i = 0;
for (; (i < data.length) && (data[i][0] == luItem); i++);
// no loop body needed here!

// do the logging outside the loop
Logger.log(i + 1);
rn = i;
Logger.log(rn);
var fsr = fs.getRange(rn,2).getValue();
Logger.log(fsr);

// and then return from the function
return i + 1;
```

Comment: I am new to coding, and putting in what you had seems to not be working.

What I would was doing with the logging was using to make sure I was grabbing tthe right information. 

What I want the script to do is lookup the luitem inside the array, return the row number for that item. Then take take that row number and use it get the value located in the 2nd column, save that as fsr and log that value. Once I know it is finding the right number I will be replacing that number with the newAmt number. That portion I have not written yet. 

So not sure the best way to setup the code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "seems to to be working"? Did you also try the standard worksheet function `VLOOKUP`?